# ASP.NET MVC 5, Knockout.js and mapping: the right way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Questions about ASP.NET MVC, Knockout.js and the mapping plugin abound. I have the following (very simple "getting started") example, which works. However, I would like feedback on whether this is the recommended approach. Primarily, I am interested in future models being significantly more complex (children, dropdowns, etc.). I feel maintaining two sets of models is not justifiable, thus my desire to use the mapping plugin.

PS: I wouldn't mind having the form submit, but I couldn't get that to work due to all different issues, apparently related to URL-encoding of string values with quotes by ko.utils.postJSON. Any updates on that would be appreciated also.

HTML

```
<h2>Simple View</h2>
<p>A simple model with 2 properties</p>
<p>Model property "Name": <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></p>
<p>Model property "Count" (just some integer): <span data-bind="text: Count"></span></p>
<form data-bind="submit: save">
    <h3>Editing</h3>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" /></p>
    <p>Count: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Count" /></p>
    <h3>Posting Back</h3>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var KoViewModel;
    $(function () {
        KoViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))');
        ko.applyBindings(KoViewModel);
    });
    var save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: location.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(KoViewModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, KoViewModel);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Server-Side

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Models.SimpleModel m = new Models.SimpleModel();

    m.Name = "Some name";
    m.Count = 1;

    return View(m);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(Models.SimpleModel fc)
{
    fc.Name += " (updated)";
    fc.Count++;
    return (new JsonResult() { Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fc) });
}
```

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: What conclusion did you reach for this question?

Comment: @rkralston I believe tomalak's answer is best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would structure the script differently.

```
function SimpleModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    // data
    self.Name = ko.observable();
    self.Count = ko.observable();

    // api
    self.load = function (data) {
        if (data) ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self);
    };
    self.save = function () {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: location.href,
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        }).done(self.load);
    };

    // init
    self.load(data);
}

// later... -------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(function () {
    var data = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))';
    ko.applyBindings( new SimpleModel(data) );
});
```

Advantages:

- All data properties of the viewmodel are explicitly defined. This helps reduce bugs because it is immediately obvious what a viewmodel looks like. It also helps reduce run-time errors because properties will exist even if they happen to be missing on the JSON input. This way, the view can always bind without any problems.
- You can move the viewmodel to a separate script file.
- The viewmodel can initialize itself from the data you pass into the constructor. This will be useful if you refactor the application - for example when your viewmodel suddenly becomes a part of a larger viewmodel.
- No awkward references to global variables or separate helper functions, the viewmodel is self-contained.
- Returning the Ajax promise from the `save` method allows you to attach extra behavior without rewiring the viewmodel:

  ```
  var vm = new SimpleModel(data);

  // programmatically save the model
  vm.save().done(function () {
      // whatever
      localStorage.setItem('lastAutoSave', Date.now());
  });
  ```

Comment: All of your advantages however completely ignore the ops stated primary concern with producing 2 models for server / client.

Comment: @rism OP did say he "feels" it's "not justifiable"... Tomalak tried to justify it. I "feel" he did it :)

Comment: @rism Well, the OP states that they are already using the mapping plugin in an attempt to remedy the situation that keeping two models would be too much work. I make a case against that notion.

Comment: I appreciate Tomalak's feedback though... It puts me in a better position to make the decision.

Comment: @Tomalak: Just to be clear, there is no middle ground of letting the mapping plugin define the properties of the model while still being able to extend it (by adding for example the .save method to it)?

Comment: If you manage all your models very tightly on the server side then in theory all you need to do is configure the mapping plugin properly so all client viewmodels are driven directly by the server models – without any predefined observables in them.

Comment: In practice you might run into A) timing problems (i.e. you try to bind to viewmodels that have not yet been mapped and therefore lack the necessary properties, which leads to run-time errors), B) dependency problems (i.e. you can't define computeds or subscribe to observables in your viewmodel definitions when all your observables are created through the mapping plugin), C) debugging problems - you can't see what a viewmodel is *supposed* to look like, because they are defined at run-time and D) consistency problems because you need to define at least *some* observables b/c of a), b), and c).

Comment: So I usually end up defining all the observables in my viewmodels thoroughly, instead of letting the mapping plugin create them. It allows me to bind to an empty viewmodel and it's way easier to reason about and debug.